# How to center align the text?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/4477/

This is code HTML:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-12 col-lg-12 " style="font-size:17px;color:white;">
<p class="text-left">- onorarii fixe;<br>
– onorarii orare, <br>
– onorarii orare şi fixe;<br>
– onorarii periodice;<br>
– onorarii de succes, în funcţie de rezultatul sau serviciul furnizat.
</p>
<p></p></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
.row
{
    background:blue;
    width:100%:
    color:white;

}
```

Each row in my text has a line beginning "-".
If we apply `"text-align: center"` my text will be aligned to the center but indents will not be arranged properly

I want the text to be exactly as it is now but aligned to the center
Can you help me please to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am really not sure what your question is.

Comment: You can't both align your text to the left and align it to the center... pick one.

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin I think he means it's all floated to that left but has a margin-left to make it centered.

Comment: @Blake after seeing your answer I agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to have a wrapper element that sets the text alignment left, then your actual text can just be a block element with width set to look nice and have `auto` left and right margins.

```css
.text-left-align-center{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.text-left-align-center p{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 30%; /*whatever width is needed for your text */
}
```

```html
<div class="text-left-align-center">
  <p>
    - onorarii fixe;<br>
    – onorarii orare, <br>
    – onorarii orare şi fixe;<br>
    – onorarii periodice;<br>
    – onorarii de succes, în funcţie de rezultatul sau serviciul furnizat.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, add this:

```
.row p {
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

and adjust the margin-left to your liking. 40% is about center, but you can change that. Also, no need to change your HTML. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BRxKX/4479/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.row
{
    background:blue;
    width:100%:
    color:white;
    margin-left:30%;
    float:left;
}
```

- Always use CSS box model for the text alignment .
- Float:left -> will help to keep the text in center even if browser width/height increases or decreases.

http://jsfiddle.net/e8z2pb3p/